# Notepad++ jump list not working from start menu

Tags: windows-7, notepad++, jumplist

I have notepad++ v5.8.7 on Windows 7 SP1. Jump list for application is not working from start menu?? It worked few months ago, i don't know when it stopped. How to fix this? Unpin and repin didn't help.

Comment: Default (Windows 7 provided) jump lists show only file types associated with the application. Changed associations are the most likely reason for why would the standard jump list stop working. Since I can't add comments here, here's something to address the NppJumpList problem in the Start menu. I developed NppJumpList. It supplies a custom recent list, that shows the same recent file list, that you can see in NPP's File menu. But... I forgot about the Start menu completely. Now I can see, that it does indeed show the standard recent list, not the custom one. Whoops.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the solution is to install [NppJumpList](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjumplist/) :

> Plugin for Notepad++. Adds windows 7
>   jump list support. Unicode version of
>   Notepad++ only.

Comment: Tried this, but it works only in taskbar, in start menu triangle exists but when I click on it nothing happens.

Comment: Did you do this optimization : [Remove Shortcut Arrow From Desktop Icons](http://www.techtip.org/how-to-remove-shortcut-arrow-from-desktop-icons/) ?

Comment: No, but this is for XP, and I see no connection with my problem? Do you have some explanation why should I do this?

Comment: Don't do this, because expressly it can cause problems with jumplists. The only explanation I can come up with is that NppJumpList does something wrong for Windows 7. You should maybe raise this question in the [Notepad++ Forums](http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums) or from [Support for NppJumpList](http://sourceforge.net/projects/nppjumplist/support).

Comment: Heh, this is not true, because my start menu jumplist stopped working before NppJump and I tried to fix this by installing NppJump. Ill try with older versions of npp when I find some time.

Comment: I was saying that the Shortcut Arrow fix is bad for jumplists. NppJump was supposed to add jumplists to Notepad++ and works on Vista, but apparently not fully on Windows 7. So it probably needs fixing.

Comment: I agree with this, but before 2 months npp jump lists worked OK on Win7, without addOn, so I thought it could be easily fixed

Comment: Did you try to uninstall Notepad++, delete the directory left-overs, and reinstall ? You might also try an older version of Notepad++ from the time that it used to work.

Comment: Last tried 5.8.1 didn't help.

Comment: Then you should go to their support forums, as their developers are probably not on superuser.com.

Comment: Hey, seeing by the comment on the post, the developer of NppJumpList is now on SU! So things might improve.

Answer (score 1):

Most applications with fly-out menus in Windows 7 that I've used just have a listing of recently used files.  Is it possible that Notepad++ currently doesn't have a listing of recently used files, or that the list is corrupted?

Comment: Who creates this file? npp+ or windows? How can I find it?

Comment: NPP+ I believe.